# Python Error: Need help resolving 2 errors (I'm a beginner)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script that downloads all the quotes of goodreads, from the given author by running: `goodreadsquotes.py` https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/1791.Seth_Godin > godin

However, I have problems executing it, since I'm a beginner in using Python. At the moment I have 2 errors. The code is as follows:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery
import sys, random, re, time


AUTHOR_REX = re.compile('\d+\.(\w+)$')

def grabber(base_url, i=1):
    url = base_url + "?page=" + str(i)
    page = PyQuery(url)
    quotes = page(".quoteText")
    auth_match = re.search(AUTHOR_REX, base_url)
    if auth_match:
      author = re.sub('_', ' ', auth_match.group(1))
    else:
      author = False
    # sys.stderr.write(url + "\n")
    for quote in quotes.items():
        quote = quote.remove('script').text().encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        if author:
          quote = quote.replace(author, " -- " + author)
        print (quote)
        print ('%')

    if not page('.next_page').hasClass('disabled'):
      time.sleep(10)
      grabber(base_url, i + 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  grabber(''.join(sys.argv[1:]))
```

After executing:

```
py goodreadsquotes.py https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/1791.Seth_Godin > godin
```

The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "goodreadsquotes.py", line 43, in <module>
    grabber(''.join(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "goodreadsquotes.py", line 34, in grabber
    quote = quote.replace(author, " -- " + author)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: instead of having a screenshot of your code, can you kindly use code-inlines to show your code and erorr

Comment: I think this code was originally written for use with Python 2. If you're using Python 3 then rather than try to diagnose and fix the problem you may find it easier to try it with Python 2.

Comment: @jacanterbury I think you're right, but can it be adopted for Python 3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot you have posted ...`encode()` method in python returns a `bytes` object, so now `quote` is no more a string, it is `bytes` object. So calling `replace()` on `quote` requires both the parameters in `bytes` not `str`. You can convert `author` and `"--"+author` to `bytes` as shown below : (line 34)

```
author_bytes = bytes(author, 'ascii')
replace_string_bytes = bytes("--"+author, 'ascii')
#converted author and the replacement string both to bytes
if author_bytes:
   quote = quote.replace(author_bytes, replace_string_bytes)
```